# Why Get-AzPublicIPAddress works with name of resource but dont work with parameter

Tags: azure, powershell, parameters

In my script i'm using the **Get-AzPublicIpAddress** cmdlet, and it's working perfectly with a VM name:

```
(Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceName "vm-ubuntu-test2311").IpAddress
```

But it doesn't work with a variable as the parameter argument:

```
$vmname = "vm-ubuntu-test2311"
(Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceName $vmname ).IpAddress
```

It passes but the value is empty

Answer (score 0):

**The way to access and get the VM public IP you can follow the below way:**

Here, I am using **Resource Group Name** and **VM name** to fetch the exact VM Resource Public IP to Avoid the conflict.

```
$name = "<Your VM Name>"
$rname = "<Your Resource Group Name>"
Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $rname -Name $name | Select-Object {$_.IpAddress}
```

#### Results:

[image]